# Output logcat to file and flush buffer without missing any logs

Tags: android, adb, logcat

Is it possible to output logcat to a file once the buffer is full, then clear the buffer without potentially missing any log messages?

I know logcat -d will output and close, and -c will clear any current logs, but that doesn't seem ideal.

This seems to potentially be a race condition where more logs are sent to logcat in between writing the file and flushing the buffer.

Comment: add some code, can't understand what ya doing.

Comment: I’m not sure what you are trying to achieve, if you need an alternative to the android logging, check out https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber. It is a great library, and you can output log messages to any thing (a file in your case) using that library

Comment: My goal is to have logcat constantly run as a service on the device which will output to a file when the buffer is full, and clear the buffer without any log messages being input into the buffer inbetween file output and clearing.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably work:

```
logcat -d -f /out.txt && logcat -c
```

Comment: I just tried it and it works.  Put it in a bash loop and it should continually output logcat to out.txt and then clear the buffer before the next output.  -d will tell it it output and then stop.  -f tells it to dump to a file.  && is bash way of executing two sequential statements on the same line.  -f clears the logcat buffer.